# PHP and MySQLi on a Ubuntu Nginx Server

Tags: php, linux, nginx, mysqli

I have been trying to use php in an Nginx server. I can't use Apache2 server. It's already in production. I have installed all the necessary requirements to run the duplicator (for Wordpress backup installation). But, it kept saying,

> Support for the PHP mysqli extension is required. Please contact your hosting provider or server administrator to enable the mysqli extension. The detection for this call uses the function_exists('mysqli_connect') call.

Stack configuration:

- Php: 7.2
- Ubuntu: 18.04 L
- Mysql: 5.7.32-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
- Nginx: 1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

When I run `sudo apt insall php-mysql`, the result is

`php-mysql is already the newest version (1:7.2+60ubuntu1).`

Result of `php -m | grep mysqli`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqlnd.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqlnd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqlnd.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqlnd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

And finally since I am using php-fpm, snippets from php.ini file is

```
extension=mysqli  <<< Current Configuration
;extension=/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mysqli.ini  <<< Tried this
;extension=mysqli.so <<< Tried This
```

## Edit 1

Information from `php info()`

```
PHP Version 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.7
```

```
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, 
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
```

Comment: Did you enable that extension in php.ini?

Comment: I uncommented this line: extension=mysqli

Comment: Everything seems fine. Did you restart Nginx? Are you sure that your nginx uses 7.2fpm? Try to `phpinfo()` somewhere (ex. index.php) and check if php version and mysql extension matches.

Comment: Did you restart FPM? CLI and FPM aren't guaranteed to use the same ini files (in fact most likely they don't), so check `phpinfo()` too.

Comment: yes. I did. It's there. I have updated the result in the post @Jonnix

Comment: /usr/lib/php/20170718 looks like a none standard path. Find the path to the actual .so file within /usr/lib/php and update the config accordingly

Comment: Have a look at `php -i` or `phpinfo()` to see the actual config paths in use - you may be editing the wrong ini file.

Comment: @RamanSailopal can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Ah, `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mysqli.ini` is definitely wrong - this needs to be the path to the `.so` file.

Comment: @halfer I am updating `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini` file

Comment: @halfer I just aimed blindly with `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mysqli.ini`